# Creating a for loop that acts as a counter but counter not properly counting

Tags: r

I have a for loop that counts whenever in a game of 4 dice rolls, it would count every time it returns a win which would be at least 1 6 in the game. However, when I run with multiple repetitions, my counter only gets up to 1.

Comment: There's an extra `{` in your function code somewhere, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an explicit `for` loop, the following code uses `replicate` to do the same and is more readable.

```
sixes_rep <- function(n = 4, r){
  draws <- replicate(r, sample(6, 4, TRUE))
  total <- sum(draws == 6)
  obs <- total/r

  theor <- 1 - (5/6)^n
  difference <- obs - theor

  cat("Theoretical prob of at least one six in", n, "dice is:", theor, "\n")
  cat("Empirical prob of at least one six after", r, "replications is:", obs, "\n")
  cat("the difference is", difference ,"\n")
  cat("trues", total, "\n")
  return(difference)
}
```